# How to sign in a user with email and password with firebase + svelte?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte

So I have a project using firebase and svelte that should allow me to create a user with email and password, sign in the same way and sign in with google.

However, I am having trouble with the second part. I can't find the documentation for the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method. I have one component to create a user and another to log in/out the user:

LogInOut.svelte

```
<script>
import { auth } from "./FirebaseConfig.svelte";
import {
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithPopup,
    signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
let email;
// somehow get the email
let password;
// somehow get the password


async function LogInWithGoogle() {
    let result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);

    if (result) {
        const user = result.user;

        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
    }
}
async function LogInWithEmail() {
    let result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password ); //THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
    if (result) {
        const user = result.user;

        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
    }
}

let visible = true;
</script>
{#if visible}
<button
    id="GoogleSignInBtn"
    on:click={LogInWithGoogle}
    on:click={() => (visible = !visible)}>Sign In With Google</button
>
<button id="EmailSignInBtn" on:click={LogInWithEmail} on:click={() => visible = !visible}
    >Sign In With Email</button
>
{/if}

{#if !visible}
<button
    id="SignOutBtn"
    on:click={() => signOut(auth)}
    on:click={() => (visible = !visible)}>Sign Out</button
>
{/if}
```

Here is the problem. I created the user in a different component, which works perfectly fine. So, if I wanted to simply export the email and password, I would need to set the context of the create user component to module. However, this breaks it, as I can't use functions outside of the script tag, which I have to do in order for it to work. Is there a way to bypass this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'm just dumb... just put in some input code to ask the user for an email and password, then sign them in with the data they inputted and firebase will automatically throw an error if the user doesn't exist or email/password is incorrect. Handling those error is all I had to do...